# Draw route between two locations on map in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have insert static map (image of map) of United States.  User will select source and destination by clicking on map and when it click show route button, route is being drawn on the map. How will I draw route between selected locations?

Comment: check this tutorial link [http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#DisplayingResults](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#DisplayingResults)

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet to draw upon the image is to use a [`canvas` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/canvas_tutorial).

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that a sensible option would be to use the Google Maps API to get you actual "route" data (as in which roads to take, distances etc):

[Google Maps JavaScript API - Routes and steps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/services.html#RoutesAndSteps)